# problem in the installation of gnome-system-tools3.0.0

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome, compiling, gcc

So during the installation of

`gnome-system-tools3.0.0`, I faced this problem:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (
               gtk+-3.0 >= 2.91
               gmodule-export-2.0
               gio-2.0 >= 2.25.3
               pango
               liboobs-1 >= 2.91.1
               system-tools-backends-2.0 >= 2.10.1
               ) were not met:

No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
No package 'pango' found
No package 'liboobs-1' found
No package 'system-tools-backends-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GST_DEPENDS_CFLAGS
and GST_DEPENDS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details
```

Does anyone have a clue of what can I do?

Comment: Please show us the command you run which resulted in that output.

Comment: alrigh: `root@root-System-Product-Name:~/Desktop/Importante/gnome-system-tools-3.0.0$  ./configure`

Comment: Why don't you install the package? `sudo apt install gnome-system-tools`

Comment: Good. Please feel free to share the solution by answering your own question.